# Невозможно сохранить файл

Tags: windows, windows-10

При попытке сохранения на диск D выдает такую ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что делать?

Comment: Ну так покажите, какие права у вас на диск D.

Comment: все спасибо, натолкнули на решение) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5xMr6yVmnY&ab_channel=remontka.provideo сделал по этому видео только вместо папки на диск )